# Windows software to check web pages for changes

Tags: windows, automation, web

I'm seeking recommendations for Windows software that will check a list of web pages for changes.

Requirements:

- Notify immediately in the application or an output file (not via email)
- Can be run manually (not a service that is always running)
- Gratis

Good to have, but not required:

- Can specify the amount of diffs that qualify as a change
- Open-source
- Portable